# When is a PubSub Subscription considered to be inactive?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

As per [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#lifecycle):

> By default, subscriptions expire after 31 days of inactivity (for instance, if there are no active connections, pull requests, or push successes). If Pub/Sub detects subscriber activity, the subscription deletion clock restarts. Using subscription expiration policies, you can configure the inactivity duration or make the subscription persistent regardless of activity. You can also delete a subscription manually.

Is subscription considered to be inactive even if there are unacked messages on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a subscription is considered inactive if there is no subscriber activity on it, even if there are unacknowledged messages available to that subscription.

Subscription expiration is a configurable subscription property as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#using_subscription_properties).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#lifecycle) you shared, I would like you to pay attention in the following statement,  taken from another part part of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#seek_to_a_time),

> An unacknowledged message is retained in a subscription for up to message_retention_duration after it is published (the default is 7 days).

Therefore, after publishing the messages to the Subscriber, these messages will be retained for 7 days (`default`), and the deletion clock will start. If there are no more calls to the subscription the *deletion clock* will continue counting towards the expiration time because there won't be any activity in the subscription. Also, note that after 7 days these unacknowledged messages will be deleted.